# DELETE with qsqlquery

Tags: qt

I'm trying to delete with qt with this code:

```
int jobId = 655;
query.prepare("DELETE FROM jobs WHERE jobId = '" + QString::number(jobId) + "'");
QString error = query.lastError().text();
if (query.exec())
    qDebug() << "DELETE ok";
else
    qDebug() << error;
```

if jobId exist all fine but if not exit too show "DELETE ok".

How can I check this situation?.

Thanks you very much

Comment: You would need to retrieve the `lastError()` after executing the query. (i.e. in the `else` part, in your case.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `DELETE` query doesn't generate error if it has nothing to delete.

You might be able to find if something was deleted with [`QSqlQuery::numRowsAffected`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#numRowsAffected).

But if you want to know if the id exists before deleting it, you have to do a separate `SELECT` request for that id.

PS: you should use `addBindValue` or `bindValue` to insert values in the query string:

```
query.prepare("DELETE FROM jobs WHERE jobId = ?");
query.addBindValue(jobId);
```

Comment: And when query is UPDATE, How can I check the same situation? I have try query.numRowsAffected() and if jobId no exist or exist always return 0.     Thnaks